# EC2 Instance cannot connect to github using SSH

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, amazon-ec2, laravel-forge

I'm trying to deploy a web with Laravel Forge and AWS. I created an EC2 instance using Laravel Forge control panel. I created a security group for this instance.

[Outbund rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnyp1.png)

[Inound rules v1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jyyB1.png)
[Inbound rules v2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZkUC.png)

All SHH connections allowed are described in this Laravel Forge guide:
https://forge.laravel.com/docs/1.0/servers/providers.html

So, the problem is when I try to install the repository I get this error into EC2 instance.

[SHH error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lYxAc.png)

I also checked that my instance's SHH public key is registered in my github account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **Outbound** rules are permitting connections on port 80 (HTTP) and port 443 (HTTPS).

However, SSH uses port 22. This is causing the connection to fail.

**You should add port 22 to the Outbound rules.**

However, it is generally considered acceptable to **Allow all outbound connections** from an Amazon EC2 instance since you can 'trust' the software running on the instance. I would recommend allowing all outbound connections rather than restricting it to specific ports.

Comment: Thanks Jhon, I unknown the possibility to allow all outbound connections. My problem was resolved